# how to get name of cell in excel with vba

Tags: excel, vba, cell

i have searched a lot but i couldnt find. Is there a simple way to get name of cell from range object  like "A30" not like "$A$30" i'm asking for without '$' sign

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `Range(...).Address(False, False)`

Comment: Hi @HTH, can you post this as a proper answer ? So the question can be marked as solved.

Comment: @Vincent, let's wait for Iivan3li request for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about removing **Absolute Reference** from a Range address you have:
The function to use is:

```
Range("UsedRange").Address([RowAbsolute],[ColumnAbsolute])
```

As example, let's suppose your Fully Absolute cell is «$A$1:$F$5000»:

1. If you want to keep **Absolute Row** then:

   `Range("$A$1:$F$5000").Address(true,false) '<---- Result: A$1:F$5000`
2. If you want to keep **Absolute Column** then:

   `Range("$A$1:$F$5000").Address(false,true)  '<--- Result: $A1:$F5000`
3. If you want **fully dynamic address (no absolute reference)** then:

   `Range("$A$1:$F$5000").Address(false,false)  '<--- Result: A1:F5000`

Hope it will help you!

Comment: yes, this was the answer i was looking for. Thank you :-)